# C/C++ allowed short-circut compiler optimization

Tags: c++, c, compiler-optimization, short-circuiting

In the following case, is the compiler allowed to optimize away the call to `foo()` and\or the entire `if` block?

```
if( foo() && 0 )
    { ... }
```

Comment: The compiler is allowed to do anything that produces the right result as defined by the C standard ... so whether foo() can be optimized away depends on what it does, and of course it can optimize away the if block because it never gets executed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From a standards point-of-view, the compiler **must** evaluate the left-hand side, i.e. `foo()` must be called:

> **[C99, 6.5.13]** Unlike the bitwise binary `&` operator, the `&&` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation;
>   there is a sequence point after the evaluation of the ﬁrst operand. If the ﬁrst operand
>   compares equal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated.

But as it knows that the body of the `if` statement can never be reached,<sup>*</sup> then it's free to omit any corresponding code for that part.

Of course, if the compiler can prove that `foo()` has no observable side-effects, then it's free to optimise that call away as well.  But that has little to do with the short-circuit behaviour.

---

<sub>* (C++-only) assuming `foo()` doesn't return a type with an overload of `operator&&`.</sub>

Comment: +1. I think \_\_attribute\_\_ ((pure)) is worth mentioning here.

Comment: @Elazar: Considering `foo()` has no arguments, and pure functions depend solely on their arguments, `foo()` really would have to return a constant. And then `constexpr` is the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler has to perform `foo` before determining that `0` means the statement in the `if` isn't executed. However, if `foo` is a very simple function that has no side-effects (doesn't alter any global state - and there is a long definition of that in the C and C++ standards), then it itself can be optimised away. Typically that only happens if `foo` is part of the same source-code.

Answer (score 1):

equivalent code:

```
int x = (int) foo();
if (x)
    if  (0)
        { ... }
```

can you "optimize away" the first line, for arbitrary foo? `foo` may be something like

```
int foo() {
    printf("x");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, if foo is defined like, say `int foo() { return 0; }`

Comment: "if". if you have complete knowledge you can always optimize away everything. It has nothing to do with the short-ciruiting.